# What are Simulated B-mode and phantom images?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

Could someone please explain what simulated B-mode and phantom images are? I've seen them in several IEEE papers. How can one create these images?

What is the formula for signal-to-noise ratio and contrast-to-noise ratio?
Please share MATLAB code for the above ratios.

Comment: Welcome to DSP SE. Could you please provide the sources for your question? (For example, those IEEE papers where you've seen these images you talk about.) Also, it would be cool if you showed some effort in trying to find methods to create them by yourself (the same goes to the formulas you ask for... have you even tried to find them?). Last but not least, asking for specific working code is off-topic in this website, so maybe you could write some code of your own and post it here so other users can check it out and make suggestions about it and stuff.

Comment: please see this linl.https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26441443 (IEEE reference paper )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[B-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_ultrasound#Modes_of_sonography) is the most elementary way to form an **image** from the Ultrasound modality. You basically shift the beam of an A-Mode, either mechanically or electronically. To simulate B-mode, you need a three dimensional model of tissue density and a sound propagation model. There are basically two methods to achieve it, you either do [ray-tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(physics)) (if the wavelength is much smaller than the distance) or you solve the [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) directly. In either of these cases you simulate ultrasound propagation through the tissue and re-construct the image that a real ultrasound machine would give you.

A [*"phantom"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaging_phantom), more generally, is an item that has been fully characterised and its measurements are known. It is used for calibration. So, for example, you know that [Water should return a zero in the Haunsfield scale and Air should return -1000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hounsfield_scale). If you scan [a phantom](http://rtigroup.com/accessories/detail/ct-phantom-set) and the image does not agree with its specifications, the machine needs to be re-calibrated / repaired.

The simplest example of a phantom in "everyday life" is that gray-scale ribbon that you see in some screen calibration utilities that direct you to tune your monitor until you can see all the bands in the ribbon, or until some patterns appear / disappear.

A software phantom is exactly the same thing but it is used to "calibrate" or assess an algorithm. You are probably talking about the [Shepp-Logan phantom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepp%E2%80%93Logan_phantom) which contains a number of fully characterised ellipses.

If you are working in [tomographic image reconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomographic_reconstruction) then you can compare the image that your technique reconstructs against the "real" image and make inferences.

To create these images, all that you have to do is create an image with shapes of known characteristics (as you can see from the Wikipedia page on the Shepp-Logan phantom).

As far as the *"...formula for signal-to-noise ration and contrast-to-noise ratio..."* is concenred, it can be found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio_(imaging)). It really depends on what you are trying to measure and how and yes, you will need a phantom for that. For more information please see [this link](http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/43/056/43056499.pdf).

Image quality assessment is [a field on its own in medical imaging](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?queryText=.QT.image%20quality%20assessment.QT.&newsearch=true).

Hope this helps.